# How to use or opt out in Android 12 SplashScreen

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-12

The new API [SplashScreen](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen#java) in Android 12 seems good but just like before the sample code in the documentation does not really help explaining the whole and proper implementation. There is also some cases where you might do some task during splash screen in our case this is to launch Firebase Auth so probably the best way is just to opt out on using this new featured API but according to lint warning it seems like it is mandatory and there is no way to opt out.

> The application should not provide its own launch screen
>
> Application-defined Launch Screen  Starting in Android 12 (API 31+),
> the application's Launch Screen is provided by the system and the
> application should not create its own, otherwise the user will see two
> splashscreen. Please check the SplashScreen class to check how the
> Splash Screen can be controlled and customized.

How about the backward compatibility for older devices, how to handle it? Is there any codelab project to play and test with?

Answer (score 7):

1. **Can we opt out of SplashScreen?**

It looks like we can't opt out as Android Team is trying to unify the app loading experience: https://9to5google.com/2021/04/21/android-12-dp3-all-apps-now-show-the-same-splash-screen-while-loading-gallery/

2. **How to use it?**

If you don't do anything then it will use `windowBackground` of the theme & your launcher icon &  dismissed as soon as your app draws its first frame.

There are bunch of properties that you can modify like background, icon etc: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen#set-theme

3. **What if I want splash to stay longer? Like fetching a local DataBase.**

You can use `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener` & make a blocking call from your `viewmodel` return if it's ready to go ahead.

**Activity:**

```
// My Launcher Activity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel : JustDelayViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val content: View = findViewById(android.R.id.content)
        content.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(
            object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
                override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                    // Check if the initial data is ready.
                    return if (viewModel.getIsReady()) {
                        // The content is ready; start drawing.
                        content.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                        true
                    } else {
                        // The content is not ready; suspend.
                        false
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }

}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class JustDelayViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun getIsReady(): Boolean {
        val result = viewModelScope.runCatching {
            runBlocking {
                //do some blocking call check for Firebase result or something
                delay(5000)
            }
            true //return the result
        }
        return result.isSuccess
    }
}
```

You can read more about this: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen#suspend-drawing

Comment: Yeah I read those before, but how are we going to handle this together with a support on older devices? It is better to have a codelab or sample project to play with.

Comment: Gee, I think it would have been easier and more flexible if Google just left things well alone in this department and let apps have a little more creative freedom.

Answer (score 5):

To complement [Mayur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67647179/3022177) for older device support.

The new `windowSplashScreen*` attributes need to be added in the `res/values-v31/style.xml` file.

Then for the legacy splashscreen it depend of the current implementation of the app.

If the application simply uses a starting theme with a custom `windowBackground` there is nothing to do since the `windowBackground` isn't used for the new splash screen (only if it's a simple color).

If the application has some visible splash screen `Activity`, there will be a double splash screen on Android 12. To solve this, the application can migrate to the `windowBackground` solution.

If the application *really* need to keep its splash screen Activity, it can update the layout to match the system splash screen on Android 12 and/or create a smooth transition from the system splash screen to the app splash screen using the `SplashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener()`

Comment: This kind of update wasn't received well by many since there are others that prefer not to have splash screen as it is completely unnecessary to other cases. Too bad this is what they did instead of making the platform more stable and having less fragmented behavior. Unifying Android is technically impossible.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use android's splash screen library - [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen)

```
android {
   compileSdk 31
   ...
}

dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha02'
}
```

This will give splash screen options in `style.xml`, you just need to create 2 style.xmls 1 for android api 31 and above and one of below api 31

```
 <style name="Theme.CustomSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">300</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.YourAppTheme</item>
</style>
```

Learn more about this library using this [example](https://proandroiddev.com/splashscreen-api-android-12-part-1-b2272e0ae98e)

Comment: Unfortunately, since the introduction of this SplashScreen me and many other people have this issue: when the app is started from VS/Android Studio,there's no icon. What's worse, if in production the app is started through a deep link, still there is no icon, just a blank splash screen. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @iBobb I will check your problem and if I found the solution I will update my answer, you can also update my answer if you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line:

```
          <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

in your style.xml file before close style tag. it`s make your default android splash transparent!